# How to get struct name inside custom validation function

Tags: validation, go

this is my struct:

```
type User struct {
  Name `validate:"custom_validation"`
}
```

this is my custom validation:

```
func customFunc(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
    // I want to get struct name inside here
    
    // do some validations...

    return true
}

validate.RegisterValidation("custom_validation", customFunc)
```

the reason is I need to do some check to the database, I need the table name for that, therefore I need the struct name, because the table name is similar to the struct name. If I hard-coded the table name this `customFunc` cannot be used to validate in other struct.

How can I do that?

ref: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-Custom_Validation_Functions

Comment: Package `validator` provides contextless validation, the result of a field validation must be the same in any structure. Introducing struct name in `customFunc` makes it context-dependent. It is wrong.

Comment: @Bens please review my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple

Get name of the field:

`fl.FieldName()`

Get value of the field:

`fl.Field().String()`

Get struct type:

`fl.Parent().Type().String()`